# Replace one color with another in photoshop while taking into account gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I've got the following image in photoshop:

[image]

which derives from a color of a certain hex code, #7f2ae8, (the 3rd square down is the most "pure color"). Let's say the first square (the lightest purple) is the pure color but with 10% opacity, the 2nd square the pure color but with 40% opacity, and the 3rd square is 100% of the pure color.

Is there a way to replace all of these colors with a new "pure" color (for example, red), while having photoshop take into account the varying %s of each of the new colors? So like my desired output would be the first square is red at 10% opacity, the second square is red at 40% opacity, 3rd square is 100% red, etc.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on construction of the file.

However, you can simply apply a **Color Overlay Layer Style** and set its blend mode to **Color**.

Here, I've merely duplicated the group of purple rectangles and apply the layer style to the new group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the transparent pixel lock in the layers panel, then when you do *Edit > Fill* to fill with a new 100% solid colour, it will have the same transparency as the image because the transparency is locked.

[image]